# unable to center div in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, center

I'm unable to center a div in IE but it's fine in Chrome and Firefox.

here's the url: http://www.hearts.co.za/blog/my-inspiration/

Current CSS:

`#content {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 692px;
}`

`.widecolumn-links {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        padding: 10px 50px;
    width: 692px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
body { text-align: center; }
body * { text-align: left; }
```

Note: At looking at your source code, you use a lot of tables for layouting. You shouldn't use tables for that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB, I tried body 
{ text-align: center; }
but it never worked.

Why did you use * in the second line of code?

Comment: I've added inline style to body `style="text-align: center"` with Developer Tools and it worked for me in IE8.